How to reduce dependency from backend devs {dependent microservices are down mostly and I just can't work}
During development, my team encounters challenges when we need to interact with external systems and microservices that are not directly related to our current project scope. These backend elements are necessary only for accessing specific parts of the development process.
For eg: I am working on a multistep form and each step calls a web service(GET API call). If I want to work only on the 3rd and the 4th steps of the form, I find it difficult to do so as often the services for the previous steps are down. This is just 1 instance, but I feel this to be blocking us all multiple times. What can be done?
Currently, we have to contact the other teams to get their services up and running and this takes time.

You can mock them for local development, there are a lot of tools for that. Or alternatively you can look into TDD.

Thanks for your suggestion. I create mocks only currently but it is difficult to mock, today one service is down, and tomorrow the other one will be down. I end up spending a lot of time creating mocks.
Anyways can you recommend some tools for creating mocks, any you specifically prefer?


Volume of mocks would also be high and difficult to manage.
I actually wanted to analyse the root of the problem. Do other people also face this kind of problem or have faced and solved for.


"today one service is down, and tomorrow the other one will be down" - you create mocks for everything and do not work with actual services. It is not ideal but it allows you to proceed. "I actually wanted to analyse the root of the problem" - we can't analyze the root cause since we don't have access to your environment. It sounds like the problems is outside of your ability to analyze/fix. You might try to pressure for a separate environment where the dependencies are stable (if it is possible).

@GuruStron thanks a lot, your suggestion helps. I wanted to check on how can we mock everything? I have explored tools like mocky and mockoon, but there, you have to create 1 mock at a time. It is a very tedious process. Any recommendations?

@GuruStron would really appreciate if you could share your recommendations. It will be a real help.

TBH do not have a lot of experience with frontend. When working close with FE guys they quite often developed stuff using mock servers with simplified repsonces.
